# Check pointer to pointer type in LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm, clang

How to check an operand is `pointer to pointer` type in `LLVM`? We can check is operand pointer or not, but how to check is it pointing to a pointer? I am using `Clang` to generate intermediate code and using `C++` for source file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can invoke `Type::getContainedType(int)` to get access to the pointee type. So it should look like this:

```
bool isPointerToPointer(const Value* V) {
    const Type* T = V->getType();
    return T->isPointerTy() && T->getContainedType(0)->isPointerTy();
}
```